# Text-to-speech for iPhone (preferably Monotouch)

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, text-to-speech

I am looking into implementing text-to-speech in an iPhone (Monotouch) app I am creating. What good such libraries are there around? If necessary I will have to map a standard iPhone library to Monotouch.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in standard iOS library with a public API.  Several apps in the App store use the [CMU flite](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/flite/) (or Festival Lite speech synthesis engine) library, for which there are ports of the library to the iOS/iPhone, perhaps [here](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2010/09/openears-speech-library-for-iphone-using-cmusphinx/).

Answer (score 0):

The Monotouch wiki has an explanation [here](http://wiki.monotouch.net/index.php?title=HowTo/Interop/Interopping_with_Open_Source_Text-to-Speech_%28TTS%29_C_libraries__for_iPhone.&galleryOffset=showall) describing how to cross-compile Flite for the iPhone and interop the libraries with Monotouch.